# Synchronized method allowing two accesses at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following method

```
public synchronized void run() 
    {

while (done.get()!=true) {

        System.out.println(">>> Golfer #"+ myID + " trying to fill bucket with "+getBallsPerBucket()+" balls.");
        golferBucket = sharedStash.getBucketBalls();
                    if(golferBucket.length == 0){
                        try {
                            sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Golfer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
        System.out.println("<<< Golfer #"+ myID + " filled bucket with "+getBallsPerBucket()+" balls, size = "+sharedStash.getSizeStash());
```

Which uses this synchronized method:

```
   public synchronized golfBall[] getBucketBalls() {

    golfBall[] bucket = new golfBall[sizeBucket];
    if (getSizeStash().intValue() >= sizeBucket) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeBucket; i++) {
            bucket[i] = stash.poll();
        }
        sizeStash.set(sizeStash.intValue() - sizeBucket);
        System.out.println("minusing");
        return bucket;
    }

    return new golfBall[0];

}
```

However when I run two different 'Golfer' threads, it is allowing the two threads to access the getBucketBalls() method at the same time. I am not sure how to fix this as I thought synchronizing the method locked access from other threads while one thread has aquired the lock. Also I read on another post that the locks work on instances, but I only have one instance of BallStash, which is where the getBucketBalls() method is in.

The output I get is:

```
 =======   River Club Driving Range Open  ========
 ======= Golfers:5 balls: 20 bucketSize:5  ======
 >>> Golfer #1 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
 >>> Golfer #2 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
 minusing
 minusing
 <<< Golfer #2 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 10
 <<< Golfer #1 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 10
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh I see, I added sample output, the threads both say that they have a thread size of 10, but one should say 15 and then 10, the output I get doesn't make sense, as the one thread should execute first and then have a value of 15 and not 10

Comment: When used in a method definition, synchronized causes a lock to be acquired on the class which owns the method before the method is executed. Are your two methods in the same class?

Comment: No, the first run() method is in the Golfer Class, and the second getBucketBalls() is in the BallStash Class. Should they be in the same class?

Comment: @Daniel In order to use "synchronized" in the method definition, they have to be in the same class. If they're in different classes, you need to synchronize on a shared object. See [This Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: Note that your Thread's run() method does not need to be synchronized. run() is only called once on the one Thread object.

Comment: @Tyler, the shared object in this case is a BallStash object, how would I synchronise on this?

Comment: please add the thread id to 'minusing' message

Answer (score 0):

Your existing approach won't work. In a comment, you stated that your methods are in different classes.

If the two methods are in different classes, using the synchronized keyword in the method definition won't help. When used in a method definition, synchronized is equivalent to synchronizing on the class definition.

This:

```
public class MyClass{
  public synchronized void aMethod(){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
public class MyClass{
  public void aMethod(){
    synchronized(this){
       // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

That means your run() method and your getBucketBalls() are not using the same object to control access. If they're not synchronizing on the same thing, nothing stops them from running simultaneously.

If you want to synchronize methods in two different classes, you need to create an Object that they can both use as a lock, e.g.:

```
Object lockObj = new Object();

public void aMethod(){
  synchronized(lockObj){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

lockObj can be any Object, so in your case you'd do

```
public void run(){
  synchronized(ballStash){
     // do work
  }
} 

public void getBucketBalls(){
  synchronized(ballStash){
    // do work
  }
}
```

Comment: So how would I use this with the run() method?

Comment: This explanation doesn't make any sense. `If the two methods are in different classes, using the synchronized keyword in the method definition won't help.`

What are you implying, that you can't add method level synchronization to prevent two external classes from accessing the method concurrently? 

Thread level synchronization works correctly when multiple threads are trying to access the same method. If the same object is visible to more than one thread then method level synchronization will suffice to prevent concurrent access.

Comment: @TechTrip could you please help me?

Comment: I would need a full example for context.

Comment: @TechTrip - The first part of my example is demonstrating why Daniel's approach isn't going to work. He stated that his methods are in different classes.

Comment: @Daniel - in your run method you need to add a synchronized block (as I did in the last part of my answer) which uses some object that's also used by a synchronized block in your getBucketBalls() method.

Comment: Tyler: your first example is incorrect, you're interpreting it as if it was marked `synchronized static`.

Comment: Whoops, crap. Nathan is right. Mine should say synchronized(this)